# java database management connection error

Tags: java, mysql

I am using the below code to make an SQL connection but am getting an error.

I am using netbeans and netbeans itself is able to connect to the database. My code for some reason not allowing me to connect and states I do not have a suitable driver. I am importing the SQL driver so I am not sure what is wrong.

Did I form something improperly?

```
May 20, 2013 11:06:18 AM sample_server.DatabaseManagement Connection
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXX:3306/javaBBS
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://XXXXXX:3306/javaBBS
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at sample_server.DatabaseManagement.Connection(DatabaseManagement.java:31)
    at sample_server.OneLiner.<init>(OneLiner.java:14)
    at sample_server.MenuSystemClass.MainMenu(MenuSystemClass.java:38)
    at sample_server.doComms.run(Sample_server.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sample_server;

import com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Version;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Aaron
 */
public class DatabaseManagement {
    DatabaseManagement(){}
    /**
     *
     */
    public void Connection() {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306/javaBBS";
        String user = "java";
        String password = "notarealpassword";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}


 try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");
```

I added the above and it still throws the same error. Do I need to register Class to DriverManager some how?

Answer (score 5):

As every JDBC Tutorial will show you, you have to call

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

to load the driver class prior to getting the `Connection` from the `DriverManager`.

Additionaly, you need to have the mysql connector in your build path.

Comment: Further reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager

Comment: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/

This tutorial doesn't show that. Can you show me how to load the driver class and add the connector to my build path?

Comment: @Aaron: The author of the tutorial seems to have forgotten that. You load the driver class with the piece of code I've posted, and you can follow the steps from the tutorial below _Before we start_ to add the connector to your build path.

Comment: You need to add `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` before you call `con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you can try:

1. Register the JDBC Driver using the method : `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` so that the driver is loaded.
2. In the connection url string after the name of the database: add a "?useSSL=false" such that it is `jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306/javaBBS?useSSL=false`
3. If neither of it works, try re-installing the JDBC Driver